# External GPS feed for HTML5 geolocation API in django-leaflet?

Tags: gps, geodjango, geolocation, html5

My goal is the following:

I'm developing a Django project. The goal is to locate places with a form. I'm using a CreateView generic view (maybe I should create it manually for more customization.

3 **optionally** ways to locate :

1. by hand
2. HTML 5 geolocation API
3. External GPS (that gives the position to HTML 5 geolocation API or directly in Django)

The first is working well.

For the last point. Would I like to know the best way and **HOW**?

1. I read location from serial with pyserial and pynmea
2. I send to a Linux or cross-platform bridge to give it HTML 5 Geolocation API (external to Django project)

OR

2. An activation button that switches from HTML 5 Geolocation API to external GPS. Latlong feeds then the leaflet-Django instance.

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346050/html5-geolocation-from-external-gps) relevant post for windows but I need make it working on Linux.

use the web geolocation from HTML 5 with the plugin *leaflet.location*.

*Django 2.1 - GeoDJango - Django-leaflet
GPS: BT-747 (serial GPS)*

Comment: I'm not sure how you are planning to send serial data to a browser. Pyserial shouldn't be able to send data to HTML5 API.

Answer (score 0):

The GPSd can read serial GPS and feed Android geolocation API or HTML 5 geolocation API for Firefox.

> firefox/mozilla, the Android smartphone operating system (from
>   version 4.0 onwards and possibly earlier; we don't know for sure when
>   the change happened) uses GPSD to monitor the phone's on-board GPS, so
>   every location-aware Android app is indirectly a GPSD client.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an answer, it appears to be a clarification of some part of the question